# How can I create a route that take an user to his/her dashboard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on a platform for different clients, every client is tracking different KPI, therefore a common project cannot be shared due to the models are different.

What I want to do is the following:

1. The user creates an account
2. Once, they have created the account, they can log in and see their
   dashboard

[image]

What I am doing is to create a different file per client for every part of the project (Models, API, server, ctr). For instance; we have 2 clients client A and client A, the project will have a folder called models (which contains the mongoose schema) therefore, I was thinking to create 2 folders inside that folder called model, client_model_A and client_model_B. And, I pretend to do the same for the APIs, the DB connection, and the server.

Just like this:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion? Or should I use another method?

Answer (score -2):

No need to copy in files just create a data table name `user_configure` Than set all configuration in `user_configure`

Comment: can you please give an example?

Comment: Like: Different Dashboard color each different user, So I store a color code in the **user_configure**  table structure = id, user_id, user_root, user_dashboard_color, others